# SQL: No Sub-Query but only Joins

Tags: sql-server, left-join, inner-join

I am trying to find an alternative to this query where no sub-select is present but only joins (left, right, inner etc).

```
select count(SC.NUMBER_C) 
from FNQP2PORTAL.SA.SEC_CAS SC
where SC.NUMBER_C not in (
select E.Reference from 
FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E
join FNQP2HQ.dbo.Classes C on C.ID = E.ClassID 
where C.Reference =  'Assembly case')
```

So, it should be something like...

```
select count(SC.NUMBER_C)
from FNQP2PORTAL.SA.SEC_CAS SC
left join  FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E on E.Reference = SC.NUMBER_C and E.Reference IS NULL
inner join FNQP2HQ.dbo.Classes C on C.ID = E.ClassID and C.Reference =  'Assembly case'
```

Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Why do you have E.Reference IS NULL as part of your left join?

Comment: I want everything in SC that doesn't exist in E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queries you posted are very different.  One is inclusive (where SC.NUMBER_C IN.... - and the other is exclusive (left outer join where E.Reference is NULL).  Because of these completely different queries, it's unclear what you're trying to do.

This is how you would accomplish your first query with a join instead of the subquery.

```
SELECT COUNT(SC.NUMBER_C) 
FROM FNQP2PORTAL.SA.SEC_CAS SC
JOIN FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E
    ON SC.NUMBER_C = E.Reference
JOIN FNQP2HQ.dbo.Classes C 
    ON C.ID = E.ClassID 
WHERE C.Reference = 'Assembly Case'
```

EDIT:

You need to use a subquery and `NOT IN` to get what you're asking for in your comment.  You can't only use joins.

```
SELECT COUNT(SC.NUMBER_C) 
FROM FNQP2PORTAL.SA.SEC_CAS SC
WHERE SC.NUMBER_C NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT E.Reference 
        FROM FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E
        JOIN FNQP2HQ.dbo.Classes C 
            ON C.ID = E.ClassID 
        WHERE C.Reference = 'Assembly Case'
    )
```

Comment: This will give me everything in SC that is also in E. I want everything in SC that doesn't exist in E

Comment: your answer is exactly as my original query. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @RicoStrydom No it's not - you were using `IN` and I am using `NOT IN`.  Did you run the query?  It's different and should be what you need.  Please let me know if it needs to be modified and I will try to help.

Comment: I noticed just now that i pasted the wrong query. The query I was supposed to past had the "NOT" in it. I updated the original post. My apologies if it caused confusion.

Comment: @RicoStrydom No problem at all - thanks for clarifying.  The reason you cannot ONLY use joins is because you are trying to left outer join to a table, wanting only NULL values - and then from THAT table you need to do an inner join.  This can't be achieved purely with joins, so a subquery becomes necessary.  I hope some SQL guru comes along and shows a slicker way of doing this, though, so I will check back on this post.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(SC.NUMBER_C) 
from FNQP2PORTAL.SA.SEC_CAS SC
INNER JOIN FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E on SC.NUMBER_C = E.Reference
INNER JOIN FNQP2HQ.dbo.Classes C on C.ID = E.ClassID 
where C.Reference =  'Assembly case'
```

Comment: Why would you post the EXACT same answer that I already provided?

Comment: We posted at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code , it may throw error as you have not share the sample data with us. But you should use exists clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(SC.NUMBER_C)     
    FROM FNQP2PORTAL.SA.SEC_CAS SC,
    FNQP2HQ.dbo.Classes C,
    FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E
     WHERE C.ID = E.ClassID  
     AND C.Reference = 'Assembly Case'
    and not exists(  
    select 1 from  FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E1  
        ON SC.NUMBER_C = E1.Reference)
```

Comment: This query will not work.  You are joining to Classes on C.ID = E.ClassID when E is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

One reason people use the WHERE IN logic is because of duplicates being returned via join.  So in this case moving the logic to inner joins could result in the count inflating.  Here's how you would work around that:

```
select count(SC.NUMBER_C) 
from FNQP2PORTAL.SA.SEC_CAS SC
inner join 
    (
        select distinct E.Reference 
        from FNQP2HQ.dbo.Entities E
        join FNQP2HQ.dbo.Classes C on C.ID = E.ClassID 
        where C.Reference =  'Assembly case'
        ) as b
    on b.reference = sc.NUMBER_C
```